# Windows 8 Metro Show Webview in Popup and pass response back OAUTH2 Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, webview, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

This is my first question so hello and thanks for your support!
I am currently developing a windows 8 store app. 
I need to login to an OAUTH website and get the response token to save as a string.
I would like this to appear in a popup, have the user login, then close once a response is received.

I can get the webview to pop up and I can navigate to the page. But how do i handle the response and close. I speak VB.

Thanks again!

Edited to add my code:

```
Dim url As New Uri("https://aurlthatidontcontrol")
WebView1.Navigate(url)
PopUp.IsOpen = True
```

MY popup opens and the login for the url is presented.
Once I log in I should get a response from that server which includes an access token
I want to get that token into my app and save it as a string, then close the popup

Comment: Please post the code you are using already. It will help in trying to find where any issues are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I figure it out.

Instead of actually calling a webview I used the web-broker authentication. [Details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh750287.aspx)

This allows the service login to "pop" on the screen and I can capture the result like this:

```
Dim webresult As WebAuthenticationResult = Await      
WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(WebAuthenticationOptions.None, StartURI, endURI)

Dim finalresponse() As String = webresult.ResponseData.ToString.Split("=")
Dim currentuserstoken As String = finalresponse(1)
Return currentuserstoken
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [InvokeScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.invokescript.aspx) method on the [WebView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br227702.aspx) class to call JavaScript code to collect information from the response and return it the calling code. If there is no script in the page you control, use "eval" as the function name and pass arguments to it.

Alternatively, use window.external.notify in JavaScript to fire the [ScriptNotify](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.scriptnotify.aspx) event (link includes an example).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I cannot use JavaScript and I don't control the page.